# (C++) Clarification needed about accessing derived functions from a vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I only have limited experience with C++ and have recently attempted to create a vector of type base that holds both objects of base type and types that inherit base.

From research online I have found that in order to access derived functions instead of the base virtual function I must use a vector of pointers of type base as follows;

```
vector<base*> base_vector
```

However, I have found that if I try to add objects to the vector in any way but the following, then iterate through the vector to access member variables (and potentially member functions) of each object, an out of bounds error is thrown;

```
base_vector.push_back(new object())
```

My question, then, is why I cannot add new objects by first instantiating them and then calling push_back if I do not want such errors. Any information would be helpful as I have not found any resources that address this specifically.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have code that is not working, share that so we can tell you.

Comment: `std::out_of_bounds` has nothing to do with polymorphism. You are accessing your vector out of bounds using `at()` method. Please provide [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to follow what exactly do you mean, but I *think* you refer to automatic allocation getting destroyed. Something among the lines of:

```
// WARNING: incorrect code
std::vector<base*> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Derived d;
  v.push_back(&d);
}

v[0]->foo();
```

The above yield an **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**.

The reason is, the lifetime of the objects pushed to the vector has already been exceeded. The "owner" of them is the automatic allocation, which is guaranteed only within the scope of the object declaration.

A similar (but not exactly the same under the hood) case, where it is easy to understand why this is not working is the following:

```
// WARNING: incorrect code
std::vector<base*> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Derived* d = new Derived();
  v.push_back(d);
  delete d;
}

v[0]->foo();
```

Assuming you understand why here, accessing the elements in the vector is a mistake, it is very similar (again, nit: not exactly the same) concept.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the error is being caused by the objects added to the vector going out of scope and subsequently trying to iterate through the vector to access member functions will cause an overflow error. Why then does adding objects via v.push_back(new object) prevent this?

Comment: @Telf Because then the object is being allocated dynamically, and is owned by the vector. Note however, that failing to release it when the vector is destroyed will cause a memory leak.